# QEMU Direct Access to Video Card (or, QEMU Video Output without X11)

Tags: command-line, windows, qemu

I have a system that boots up into Linux at power on and then needs to boot into Windows XP Embedded.  After messing around with kexec and grub4dos, things aren't working out too well.

One idea that has been brought up is running Windows XP Embedded inside of QEMU instead of live booting from Linux to Windows.

The problem here is that the Linux OS is not running an X server and I would like to keep it that way.

Is there a way to run QEMU with direct access to the video card so the virtualized OS (in my case Windows XP Embedded) can output directly to the monitor?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, although it depends on the actual hardware as well and you are going to need QEMU > 1.3 and PCI based card (no AGP, I'm afraid). The keywords you want to search for are **VFIO** and **pass-through** (in all of its forms and misspellings).